# Disabled date if there is a date between start and end php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have user table data with a date value, where I am a little confused when I want to give a notification if there is a new date and the new date is on an existing date it will be given a warning. how to solve this problem

```
tb_user
+----+--------+------------+------------+
| id | user   |   Start    |   Finish   |
+----+--------+------------+------------+
| 1  | John   | 2017-12-05 | 2014-12-06 |
| 2  | John   | 2017-12-07 | 2014-12-09 |
| 3  | Smith  | 2017-12-03 | 2014-12-06 |
| 4  | Smith  | 2017-12-07 | 2014-12-10 |
+----+--------+------------+------------+
new value john = start 2017-12-08 and finish 2017-1210
```

from the table above for example I will add a new date on behalf of john start on 2017/12/08 and finish on 2017/12/10, because the date 2017/12/08 is already between 2017/12/07 - 2017/12 / 09 then I can not add the data by displaying the caption. I've made a query but a little unsure how to solve it?

```
$maxDate = $this->db->query('select max(start) as maxD, min(finish) as minD  from tb_user where user = "'.$row->user.'" ');
$maxDate = $maxDate->row_array();

if($row->start < $maxDate['maxD'] ){
    echo '<label class="text-danger">booking</label>';
}else{
    echo '<label class="text-success">empty</label>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you do **not** want is a start date that is already part of another time span. 
If it lays in another time span the start date of the time span will be smaller or equal to your start date and the finish date will be bigger or equl. As a condition it is expressed as: `start <= date AND finish >= date`.
time spans that match this condition will overlap with your new time span.

The problem of working with `MIN` and `MAX` in your attempt is, that you might have gaps in the time spans, which will not be considered that way.

You can add this condition to your SQL query. This can either be done by using the Codeigniter `query` method you used already, which lets you handle the escaping and all other stuff, or by using the CodeIgniter `QueryBuilder` methods, which will do everything for you.

Using the query method:

```
$maxDate = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE start <= "' . $row->start . '" AND finish >=  "' . $row->start . '"');
```

Using the querybuilder:

```
$this->db->select(); // Giving no parameter is equal to SELECT *
$this->db->from('tb_user');
$this->db->where('start <=', $row->start); // $this->db->where('fieldname operator', value);
$this->db->where('finish >=', $row->start); // If you do not add an operator to the first parameter the operator will be = by default
$maxDate = $this->db->get();
```

To make sure that the time spans do not overlap you should check the same for the finish dates of your row aswell:

Using the query method:

```
$maxDate = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE ( start <= "' . $row->start . '" AND finish >=  "' . $row->start . '" ) OR ( start <= "' . $row->finish . '"AND finish >=  "' . $row->finish . '" )');
```

Using the querybuilder:

```
$this->db->select(*);
$this->db->from('tb_user');
$this->db->where('start <=', $row->start);
$this->db->where('finish >=', $row->start);
$this->db->or_where('start <=', $row->finish);
$this->db->where('finish >=', $row->finish);
$maxDate = $this->db->get();
```

This condition only works without parantheses, because the `AND` operator is stronger than the `OR` operator and no other where-clauses are present. If you have to add other where-clauses you need to add paranethsis in the querybuilder aswell. Consider, that the last `where` method has another structure than the rest. Because you need to prepend the closing bracket to the query you need to add it to the right and therefore to the value side. The querybuilder yet escapes the second parameter and would therefore escape the closing bracket aswell. To prevent that it is possible to give only one parameter to the `where` method, containig the escaped value and the closing bracket.

```
$this->db->select(*);
$this->db->from('tb_user');
$this->db->where('(start <=', $row->start);
$this->db->where('finish >= ', $row->start);
$this->db->or_where('start <=', $row->finish);
$this->db->where('finish >= "' . $row->finish . '")');
$maxDate = $this->db->get();
```

The queries will return all rows that collide, so only if the result of this query is empty, the new dates can be added. This can be checked with the `num_rows` method.

```
if ($maxDate->num_rows() > 0) {
    echo '<label class="text-danger">booking</label>';
} else {
    echo '<label class="text-success">empty</label>';
}
```